# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ', How to use user-inputed values as indexes in lists

Tags: python

I am trying to teach myself how to program and therefore building one player yahtzee game (zero previous experience) and have gotten to the point where the user inputs the dice he wishes to reroll.

```
while True: 

turn1 = raw_input("Would you like to cast your first throw?")

if (turn1 == "y"):

    first_roll = roll()
    print_all_5(first_roll)
    print("You have rolled a: " + " ".join(str(first_roll)))

    if (raw_input("Would you like to reroll any if your dice?") == "y"):
        print("Please input which dice you would like to reroll (first, second, third etc) with one digit")
        rerolled_dice1 = raw_input("I want to reroll dice/dices number: ")
        for x in rerolled_dice1:
            first_roll[int(x) -1] = randint(1,6)
elif (turn1 == "n"):
    print("Well why even bother wasting your battery life to run these measily 106 lines of code?")
else:
    print("Respond only with 'y' for yes and 'n' for no please x_X")
```

What I am trying to do is store the user inputed values into the list variable **rerolled_dice1** and then to iterate through it and convert the values stored as str into int and use them as indexes for **first_roll** which holds the values corresponding to the original set of cast dice and change them to a random number.

When I run the code the traceback I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\projects\oneplayer.py", line 110, in <module>
   first_roll[int(x) -1] = randint(1,6)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Can you please explain why this happens? Tried to do some research, my guess is it can't convert the space in between the inputs, in that case how do I differentiate between inputting 1, 2 and  3 and 123? If not, any suggestions?

P.S. Haven't decided the general flow of the game,  still trying to piece up bits of functionality, which will later try and arrange into a more sensible main function. If anyone has any structural/control flow advice for turn-based dice games, will also be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

The code before this point for reference (please ignore the started and abandoned documentation)

```
from random import randint 

def roll():
        dice_values = []

        for x in range (5):
            dice = randint(1,6)
            dice_values.append(dice)


        return dice_values

def create_dice():
        dice = []                  # create empty list - main dice
        for i in range(3):         #loop building a dice list containing three row sublists
            row = ["*"] * 3        #create row containing three lists each holding a str
            dice.append(row)       #append row list to dice list 
        return dice                #!! important return dice list from function


def print_dice(dice):            # prints out dice list neatly
    for row in dice:         # uses the index to access lst value in dice lst           
        print(" ".join(row)) # joins strings with space in between

def dice1 (dice): 
    dice[1][1] = "O"
    return dice


def dice2 (dice): 
    dice[0][0] = "O"
    dice[2][2] = "O"
    return dice

def dice3 (dice):
    dice[0][0] = "O"
    dice[1][1] = "O"
    dice[2][2] = "O"
    return dice


def dice4 (dice): 
    dice[0][0] = "O"
    dice[0][2] = "O"
    dice[2][0] = "O"
    dice[2][2] = "O"
    return dice

def dice5 (dice): 
    dice[0][0] = "O"
    dice[0][2] = "O"
    dice[1][1] = "O"
    dice[2][0] = "O"
    dice[2][2] = "O"
    return dice


def dice6 (dice): 

    dice[0][0] = "O"
    dice[0][2] = "O"
    dice[1][0] = "O"
    dice[1][2] = "O"
    dice[2][0] = "O"
    dice[2][2] = "O"
    return dice

def print_all_5(elist):
    print("\n")
    for x in elist:
        if x == 1:
            print(print_dice(dice1(create_dice())))
        elif x == 2:
            print(print_dice(dice2(create_dice())))
        elif x == 3:
            print(print_dice(dice3(create_dice())))
        elif x == 4:
            print(print_dice(dice4(create_dice())))
        elif x == 5:
            print(print_dice(dice5(create_dice())))
        else:
            print(print_dice(dice6(create_dice())))
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Did you mean `int(x)` instead of `int(rerolled_dice1)`?

Comment: Also you'll notice a pattern. `dice3` does the same thing as `dice1` and `dice2`. `dice5` does everything `dice6` does except `dice[1][2] = 'O'`.

Comment: Thank you for the spot, updated the traceback as well. Do you mean I can write the dice with only a couple of functions?

Comment: The plot thickens. Use `for x in rerolled_dice1.strip().split():`

Comment: that worked, much appreciated ;D

Comment: Yup. Glad to help.